# How to stop Catalina from contacting Apple servers when executing programs?

Tags: macos, catalina, security, firewall, gatekeeper

I'm a software developer and as such I build and run programs hundreds of times per day. I've noticed that since I started using Catalina, after compiling and linking there is a delay (which can be seconds) when the internet is slow or having problems (I have bad internet often). If I disable wifi and rebuild, the delay goes away.

How can I disable this so my builds run faster?

Comment: Created an account, just to say - you can use Wireshark to see exactly what is being sent and when if you're curious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does macOS phone home to Apple's servers before running an app for the first time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391379/does-macos-phone-home-to-apples-servers-before-running-an-app-for-the-first-tim)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, as a security measure, macOS Catalina sends some small info (can be seen by packet size) about unsigned executables to the Apple servers.

A simple  C program as illustrated in ..

- [Does macOS phone home to Apple's servers before running an app for the first time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391379/does-macos-phone-home-to-apples-servers-before-running-an-app-for-the-first-tim)

.. can demonstrate the lag in startup on poor internet connection conditions.

- https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/catalina-executables.html

The article has detailed observations, tests and commentary on the process.

You can block the `syspolicyd` process from connecting to the internet, and it won't hinder its normal functioning locally, using a firewall.

I use LuLu, since it's free. A lot of people use Little Snitch.

- https://github.com/objective-see/LuLu
- https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

Many other apps also ping their servers on startup or quitting: Firefox,
Adobe,
Sublime Text etc.

Other threads:

- [Which free alternatives to Little Snitch can I use to block internet traffic per applications?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94282/which-free-alternatives-to-little-snitch-can-i-use-to-block-internet-traffic-per)
- [How can I get the exact URLs/requests that a program is trying to connect to?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40468/how-can-i-get-the-exact-urls-requests-that-a-program-is-trying-to-connect-to)
- [Reasons to prefer Little Snitch over the built-in firewall](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34150/reasons-to-prefer-little-snitch-over-the-built-in-firewall)
- [Firewall for outgoing connections](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86517/firewall-for-outgoing-connections/86526#86526)

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Application Firewall` to control what app on your mac connects to the internet.

[Lulu](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) is free and opensource. [Radiosilence](https://radiosilenceapp.com/) and [TripMode](https://tripmode.ch/) are two other very affordable alternative app firewalls that are simpler to use than Lulu. [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) and [HandsOff](http://www.oneperiodic.com/products/handsoff/) are more advanced with more features (and hence costlier).

If you like controlling what apps connect to the internet on your mac,think carefully before upgrading to macOS Big Sur. [Apple has crippled application firewalls on macOS Big Sur](https://sneak.berlin/20201112/your-computer-isnt-yours/), to specifically allow all Apple authorised software to bypass application firewalls and some VPNs, and connect to the internet whenever it wants even if you have blocked them on your firewall.

**Update**: Apple claimed that the issue with macOS Big Sur was a bug and it has been fixed now.

Comment: It's worth noting that Apple has promised to implement options to disable the feature 'within the year' on Big Sur. For the time being, you could just disable gatekeeper altogether.

Comment: @benwiggy What feature has Apple promised to disable? And can you provide a source?

Comment: See the last section on this Support Page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491

Comment: Thanks for the source. I see they've promised to provide an option to disable it next year. But still, there is nothing to celebrate here as after Apple's subversion of macOS Big Sur that prevents the blocking of some Apple apps it's all redundant - that's the major thing they need to fix to regain trust again.

Comment: Change is gonna come :-) https://apple.slashdot.org/story/21/01/14/141248/apple-removes-feature-that-allowed-its-apps-to-bypass-macos-firewalls-and-vpns